# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException when iterating over a map and changing values?

Tags: java, dictionary, loops

I've got a map containing some keys (Strings) and values (POJOs)

I want to iterate through this map and alter some of the data in the POJO.

The current code I've inherited removes the given entry, and adds it back in after making some changes to the POJO.

This doesn't work well, since you shouldn't be modifying a map whilst your iterating through it (method is synchronised, but ConcurrentModificationException still appears)

**My question is**, if I need to iterate over a map and change values, what are the best practices/methods I can use for doing so? To create a separate map and build that up as I go, then return the copy?

Comment: Does the entry in the map need to be removed in order to modify it?

Comment: @Jeremy, the POJO itself needs its state changed, so should be able to remain in the map

Comment: Then you shouldn't be getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you aren't removing any of the values. Just modifying the state of the value wont be a problem, sans any external factors.

Comment: it's funny to point out that the terminology is a bit confusing *ConcurrentModificationException* (a "CoMo" for short ;) makes you think there's a "concurrency" issue even though a CoMo can (and typically does) happen when only one thread is accessing the data structure.  :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Two options:**

### Option 1

> The current code I've inherited removes the given entry, and adds it back in after making some changes to the POJO.

Are you changing the *reference* to the POJO? E.g., so the entry points to something else entirely? Because if not, there's no need to remove it from the map at all, you can just change it.

### Option 2

If you *do* need to actually change the reference to the POJO (e.g., the value of the entry), you can still do that in place by iterating over the `Map.Entry` instances from `entrySet()`. You can use `setValue` on the entry, which doesn't modify what you're iterating over.

Example:

```
Map<String,String>                  map;
Map.Entry<String,String>            entry;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>>  it;

// Create the map
map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("one", "uno");
map.put("two", "due");
map.put("three", "tre");

// Iterate through the entries, changing one of them
it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    entry = it.next();
    System.out.println("Visiting " + entry.getKey());
    if (entry.getKey().equals("two"))
    {
        System.out.println("Modifying it");
        entry.setValue("DUE");
    }
}

// Show the result
it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    entry = it.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

The output (in no particular order) is:

> Visiting two
>   
> Modifying it
>   
> Visiting one
>   
> Visiting three
>   
> two=DUE
>   
> one=uno
>   
> three=tre

...without any modification exception. You will probably want to synchronize this in case something else is also looking at / mucking with that entry.

Comment: Very good answer. Just to add, here's the code for the iterator in question: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html Scroll down to line 94, where the class AbstractMapIterator declared.

Answer (score 18):

Iterating over a `Map` and adding entries at the same time will result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` for most `Map` classes.  And for the `Map` classes that don't (e.g. `ConcurrentHashMap`) there is no guarantee that an iteration will visit all entries.

Depending on exactly what it is you are doing, you may be able to do the following while iterating:

- use the `Iterator.remove()` method to remove the current entry, or
- use the `Map.Entry.setValue()` method to modify the current entry's value.

For other types of change, you may need to:

- create a new `Map` from the entries in the current `Map`, or
- build a separate data structure containing changes to be made, then applied to the `Map`.

And finally, the Google Collections and Apache Commons Collections libraries have utility classes for "transforming" maps.

Answer (score 8):

For such purposes you should use the collection views a map exposes:

- [keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) lets you iterate over keys. That won't help you, as keys are usually immutable.
- [values()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) is what you need if you just want to access the map values. If they are mutable objects, you can change directly, no need to put them back into the map.
- [entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) the most powerful version, lets you change an entry's value directly.

Example: convert the values of all keys that contain an upperscore to uppercase

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getKey().contains("_"))
        entry.setValue(entry.getValue().toUpperCase());
}
```

Actually, if you just want to edit the value objects, do it using the values collection. I assume your map is of type `<String, Object>`:

```
for(Object o: map.values()){
    if(o instanceof MyBean){
        ((Mybean)o).doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: entrySet() donesnt let you change the entry's key only the value.

Comment: True. It took 9 year for someone to catch that error :-)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new map (mapNew). Then iterate over the existing map (mapOld), and add all changed and transformed entries into mapNew. After the iteration is complete, put all values from mapNew to mapOld. This might not be good enough if the amount of data is large though.

Or just use [Google collections](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) - they have `Maps.transformValues()` and `Maps.transformEntries()`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide a proper answer, you should explain a bit more, what you are trying to achieve.

Still, some (possibly useful) advice:

- **make your POJOs thread-safe** and do data updates on POJOs directly. Then you do not need to manipulate the map.
- use [**ConcurrentHashMap**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
- keep on using **simple HashMap**, but build a new map on each modification and switch maps behind the scenes (synchronizing the switch operation or using [AtomicReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html))

Which approach is best depends heavily on your application, it is difficult to give you any "best practice". As always, **make your own benchmark** with realistic data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**ConcurrentHashMap**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

From JavaDoc,

> A hash table supporting full
>   concurrency of retrievals and
>   adjustable expected concurrency for
>   updates.

For ConcurrentModificationException to occur, generally:

> it is not generally permissible for
>   one thread to modify a Collection
>   while another thread is iterating over
>   it.

Comment: That's not the point, concurrent access is not needed. entrySet() or values() is what the OP should use

Comment: @seanizer, Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I simply thought that he could simply wrap his map inside the ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, somewhat tortured, is to use [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) as your map's value type. In your case, that would mean declaring your map of type

```
Map<String, AtomicReference<POJO>>
```

You certainly don't need the *atomic* nature of the reference, but it's a cheap way to make the value slots rebindable without having to replace the entire `Map.Entry` via `Map#put()`.

Still, having read some of the other responses here, I too recommend use of [`Map.Entry#setValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue%28V%29), which I had never needed nor noticed until today.