# ConcurrentModificationException ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream, concurrentmodification

In socket programming, I am trying to send an object to server, then it is throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`. It is not throwing exception in every iteration. 
I am trying to send a `Serializable` object on server.

Code on client -

```
Message request = new Message();
        request.setMessage("request");
        request.setSourceNode(node);
        System.out.println("cs enter "+ node.getId());
        for(Integer i : clientThread.keySet())
        {
            //clientThread.get(i).sendMessage("request");
            clientThread.get(i).sendMessage(request);
        }
```

Code on server -

```
public synchronized void sendMessage(Message send)
     {
         //System.out.println("Client request time stamp" + main.node.getRequestTimestamp());
         send.setDestinationNode(destinationNode);
         //System.out.println(send.getMessage() + " " + send.getSourceNode().getId() + " "+ send.getDestinationNode().getId());
         try {
            oos.writeObject(send);
            oos.reset();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

StackTrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at Client.sendMessage(Client.java:45)
    at Main.csEnter(Main.java:176)
    at Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Comment: Why send that using the serialization API? Why not use, say, JSON instead?

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well.

Comment: A possible reason is that you are changing the number of client threads while traversing it. Including or removing clients while sending the messages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078518/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-iterating-over-a-map-and-chang

Comment: I am not modifying the client threads hashmap once initialize and using the same every time to send the message. My code is working for first 4 iterations and after that it is throwing this exception.

Comment: If the exception is thrown from writeObject ... Does Message contain any list?

Comment: Message class : public class Message implements Serializable{
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private String message;
 private Node sourceNode;
 private Node destinationNode;}

Comment: Post the stack trace as suggested by @NAMS

Comment: What about the Node class? Please, update your question with Message and Node class. I've seen the first one already in the comments but may be useful for others.

Comment: I got the issue. In message, I am passing source node and destination node. In those node, one arraylist is modifying that why it throws concurrent exception. I removed that arrayList from the node and it worked. But before closing this thread, can anyone tell me will this issue be there for HashMaps as well....Many thanks for your immediate responses

Comment: Yes, it may be produced from a HashMap as well. You can try using ConcurrentHashMap.